# AIX: using grep command to log two lines from a file

Tags: shell, logging, awk, grep, aix

Basically oracle audit entries stored as `.aud` files in my AIX system

```
/oracle/SBX/saptrace/audit/
```

The entries of these files looks something like this :

```
Tue Jul  2 08:41:53 2013 +02:00
LENGTH : '159'
ACTION :[6] 'COMMIT'
DATABASE USER:[1] '/'
PRIVILEGE :[6] 'SYSDBA'
CLIENT USER:[6] 'orasbx'
CLIENT TERMINAL:[5] 'pts/0'
STATUS:[1] '0'
DBID:[10] '1854349635'

Tue Jul  2 08:41:53 2013 +02:00
LENGTH : '159'
ACTION :[6] 'COMMIT'
DATABASE USER:[1] '/'
PRIVILEGE :[6] 'SYSDBA'
CLIENT USER:[6] 'orasbx'
CLIENT TERMINAL:[5] 'pts/0'
STATUS:[1] '0'
DBID:[10] '1854349635'

Tue Jul  2 08:42:16 2013 +02:00
LENGTH : '222'
ACTION :[68] 'update SAPPRD.USR02 set uflag=64 where BNAME='CANAS' and MANDT='000''
DATABASE USER:[1] '/'
PRIVILEGE :[6] 'SYSDBA'
CLIENT USER:[6] 'orasbx'
CLIENT TERMINAL:[5] 'pts/0'
STATUS:[1] '0'
DBID:[10] '1854349635'
```

Now i have schedule a shell script in crontab for it to run every three hours.

Script is something like this:

```
#/bin/sh
grep -i USR02 /oracle/SBX/saptrace/audit/*.aud > /EDB/log/check_audit_dest.log
grep -i USH02 /oracle/SBX/saptrace/audit/*.aud >> /EDB/log/check_audit_dest.log
grep -i TCURR /oracle/SBX/saptrace/audit/*.aud >> /EDB/log/check_audit_dest.log
grep -i REGUH /oracle/SBX/saptrace/audit/*.aud >> /EDB/log/check_audit_dest.log
grep -i LFB1 /oracle/SBX/saptrace/audit/*.aud >> /EDB/log/check_audit_dest.log
grep -i LFA1 /oracle/SBX/saptrace/audit/*.aud >> /EDB/log/check_audit_dest.logs
```

What this script does is if there is any operations these tables it log that line into  `/EDB/log/check_audit_dest.log`

Like this:

```
# cat /EDB/log/check_audit_dest.log
/oracle/SBX/saptrace/audit/sbx_ora_13828348_1.aud:ACTION :[68] 'update SAPPRD.USR02 set uflag=64 where BNAME='CANAS' and MANDT='000''
/oracle/SBX/saptrace/audit/sbx_ora_8847374_1.aud:ACTION :[67] 'update SAPPRD.USR02 set uflag=0 where BNAME='CANAS' and MANDT='000''
```

Now what i want is apart from that line i also want first line of every entry to be log in that log file(for example:`Tue Jul  2 08:42:16 2013 +02:00`).

Thank you

Comment: Can you install GNU grep on that machine? Using GNU grep's context line controls, you can easily get lines of leading context before matching line using `-B`.

Answer (score 3):

Given the sample input you posted, all you need is:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '/USR02|USH02|TCURR|REGUH|LFB1|LFA1/ {print FILENAME, $1, $3}' file
file Tue Jul  2 08:42:16 2013 +02:00 ACTION :[68] 'update SAPPRD.USR02 set uflag=64 where BNAME='CANAS' and MANDT='000''
```

If that doesn't do it, post some more representative input and expected output.

Explanation as requested below by fedorqui

- `RS=` => records are separated by blank lines
- `-F'\n'` => fields within a record are separated by newlines
- `/USR02|USH02|TCURR|REGUH|LFB1|LFA1/` => look for records that
  contain any of the `|`-separated strings
- `print FILENAME, $1, $3` => print the name of the current file, and the 1st and 3rd lines/fields of the current record, the 1st line being the date and the 3rd being the ACTION.

Comment: Really interesting way of solving it, @EdMorton. In order to award the bounty to a good and documented answer, Would it be possible to have a little explanation about the logic? thanks!

Comment: @fedorqui - explanation added.

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton ! Both answers are quite good, don't know to whom I will give the bounty :)

Comment: @fedorqui - by treating each input block as a record in awk, you can print any line (field) from the record, including one AFTER the line that contains the matching pattern. With Kent's array-based solution, you'd need to modify it to do the test after all lines of a record have been read in and duplicate the logic in the END section. With the record-based one you can look for an RE in the whole record at one time or in individual lines/fields, with the array-based you need to just look in each line individually. The array-based one is gawk-specific as written due to deleting a whole array.

Comment: Another way to think of it - One way awk automatically populates both an array of lines ($1, $2, etc.) and a string ($0) of the whole record for every record and applies the condition/action rule at the end of reading every record. The other way you need to manually create/populate/destroy an array of lines (a[1], a[2], etc.) and you'd need to manually create a string for the whole record if you wanted to test/print/etc. it and you'd need to duplicate any condition/action logic in the main body and in the END section if you wanted it applied to the whole record. Just let awk do what it does...

Comment: Well done, I award this bounty to you because of the smart way of using `RS` and `F` to work with paragraphs. Thank you a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Ed Morton gave an awk solution with setting `RS` and `FS`.
Here is another solution with awk:

```
awk '!$0{delete a;next}{a[NR]=$0}/USR02|USH02|TCURR|REGUH|LFB1|LFA1/{print a[NR-2];print $0}' file
```

***the first part `!$0{delete a;next}` could be removed if your file is not a huge monster:***

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}/USR02|USH02|TCURR|REGUH|LFB1|LFA1/{print a[NR-2];print $0}' file
```

output with your input:

```
kent$  awk '{a[NR]=$0}/USR02|USH02|TCURR|REGUH|LFB1|LFA1/{print a[NR-2];print $0}' f                                                                                        
Tue Jul  2 08:42:16 2013 +02:00
ACTION :[68] 'update SAPPRD.USR02 set uflag=64 where BNAME='CANAS' and MANDT='000''
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, @Kent. Could you update with some explanation about the `!$0{delete a;next}` part? The rest is clear and looks very fine.

Comment: @fedorqui  with `!$0{delete a;next}` I try to avoid to save all lines in array. we just save each block. if the line is empty, which is a new block beginning, I delete the existing array `a`, and read next line.

Comment: nice, now I see. You are using `a` as an array to store all the lines that will be needed. I like it, it makes it complicated to decide to whom I will give the bounty :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @Kent. It is a pity I cannot award twice :( I liked Ed Morton's the most because of the way of *re-thinking* `RS` and `F`. Anyway I also learnt a lot from your answer, so thanks again!

Comment: @fedorqui it is totally ok. If I do this job, I would set RS and FS too. Ed is awk master! he deserves the bounty.

Comment: Thanks Kent and fedorqui. @fedorqui - to be be clear, though, awk IS record-based, not line-based (like sed) so I'm not re-thinking how to use RS and FS. When working on any text manipulation problem, you should always start by asking yourself how the input is naturally separated into records and so how you can specify the RS and FS for awk to reflect your input.

Comment: I agree, @EdMorton, although I would say they we normally tend to use characters as FS and `\n` as RS. So maybe instead of saying *re-thinking* I could have said *rememebering how powerful and versatile can RS and FS be*.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it like this?

```
grep -Ei "USR02|USH02|TCURR|REGUH|LFB1|LFA1" -B 2 file
```

`grep -e` admits multiple parameters. So instead of `grep -i ONE` and then `grep -i TWO`, you can do `grep -Ei "ONE|TWO"`.

With `-B 2` what you do is to print the two previous lines of the matched line.

#### Test

All together will make the following:

```
$ grep -Ei "USR02|USH02|TCURR|REGUH|LFB1|LFA1" -B 2 file
Tue Jul  2 08:42:16 2013 +02:00
LENGTH : '222'
ACTION :[68] 'update SAPPRD.USR02 set uflag=64 where BNAME='CANAS' and MANDT='000''
```

and if you do not want the line in the middle,

```
$ grep -Ei "USR02|USH02|TCURR|REGUH|LFB1|LFA1" -B 2 file | grep -v LENGTH
Tue Jul  2 08:42:16 2013 +02:00
ACTION :[68] 'update SAPPRD.USR02 set uflag=64 where BNAME='CANAS' and MANDT='000'
```

Comment: Apparently AIX' grep does not have context line controls (`-A`, `-B`, and `-C`): http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds2%2Fgrep.htm

Comment: Oh, I see. It would be a matter of trying something with http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/08/print-lines-before-pattern-linux.html or http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/sed.html

Comment: FWIW all of the awk "answers" I've seen posted at theunixschool.com have been nonsense, I wouldn't trust anything on that site.

Comment: I figure I should back that up a bit, so: here's the way to REALLY print a matched line plus the 2 lines before it using a buffered approach: `awk '{a[NR%x]=$0} /Linux/{for (i=1;i<=x;i++) print a[(NR+i)%x]}' x=3 file`. In reality, of course, you'd want to make both scripts more robust to handle the case where the pattern is matched before there's 2 lines in the buffer, but just comparing apples to apples.