# Columns to Rows Conversion in Unix shell

Tags: unix

I have an input;

```
8765843279  "dma_code":"501","dma_region";"NEW YORK, NY","check_fpc_cookie":"-1","check_tpc_cookie":"1"
```

I would like the Output as;

```
8765843279       dma_code                 501
8765843279        dma_region               NEW YORK, NY
8765843279        check_fpc_cookie          -1
8765843279        check_tpc_cookie            1
```

Please could someone assist?

Answer (score 0):

This can make it:

```
$ awk -v RS="," -F"\"" 'NR==1{v=$1}{print v, $2, $4}' file
8765843279   dma_code 501
8765843279   dma_region NEW YORK NY
8765843279   check_fpc_cookie -1
8765843279   check_tpc_cookie 1
```

#### Explanation

It is based on [this solution by Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17929536/1983854).

- `RS=","` => records are separated by commas.
- `-F"\""` => fields within a record are separated by quotes `"`.
- `NR==1 {v=$1}` stores the value of first record.
- '{print v, $2, $4}' prints value + 2nd field + 4th field. 2nd and 4th position are based on cutting the fields with the field separator, that was set to `F="\""`.